# how to write the sql queries to hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

```
id   name     date
1.   ask    2018-04-25 12:30:59
2.   msk    2018-04-25 12:40:43
3.   sdf    2017-05-25 12:42:34

id=int---->in java id-->int
name=varchar(25)----> in java name-->string
date=datetime------->in java date--->Timestamp

my sql query=select * from table where year(date)='2018';

o/p:1.   ask    2018-04-25 12:30:59
    2.   msk    2018-04-25 12:40:43
select * from table where month(date)='05'
o/p:3.   sdf    2017-05-25 12:42:34


please help me i dont know 
how to write this query in hibernate
```

How to write the above queries in hibernate? I have tried lot things but I didn't get any solution. If I use `to_char()` in hibernate it will give a unexpected token error.

Comment: WHY do You write sql queries to hibernate on the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to use to_char() function. Hibernate supports year and date functions.

Refer this link: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html
and look under "14.10. Expressions".

So your hql would simply look like this:

```
select t from table t where YEAR(t.date)='2018';

and select t from table t where MONTH(t.date)='05';
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use `to_char()` method here. you can simply use this query inside your Dao Implementation class.

for years:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from table where year(date) = :year")
       .setParameter("year",2018)
       .list();
```

for Months

```
session.createSQLQuery("select * from table where month(date) = :month")
       .setParameter("month",05)
       .list();
```